# Did Hermione kill Fenrir Greyback?

Tags: harry-potter, hermione-granger

Judging by the quote below, we see that Hermione shot some spell at Greyback that knocked him over and caused a great deal of pain on its own …

> ‘NO!’ shrieked Hermione, and with a deafening blast from her wand
>   Fenrir Greyback was thrown backwards from the feebly stirring body of
>   Lavender Brown. He hit the marble banisters and struggled to return to
>   his feet. Then, with a bright white flash and a crack, a crystal ball
>   fell on the top of his head and he crumpled to the ground and did not
>   move.
>   - *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 32*

However, that last line is a bit vague. Did the crystal ball cause the white flash and crack, or did Hermione cast another spell on purpose that caused the ball to drop? So in essence Hermione would have killed Greyback on purpose, if in fact he is dead.

So two intertwined questions really … **Is Fenrir Greyback dead, and did Hermione kill him?**

Comment: You need to finish the book.

Comment: Hermione didn't kill him, she knocked him back into the stair and Professor Trelawny beaned him with her crystal ball.

Comment: @Axelrod, I did... a long time ago... in a galaxy far, far away. I probably need to reread them! I saw that on the *All About Lavender Brown* Pottermore feature.

Comment: It's the worst missing thread in the series that the Remus Lupin + werewolf-that-bit-him Fenrir + former friend and *silver handed(!)* Peter Pettigrew storyline didn't end in some kind of epic showdown/redemption.

Comment: To answer your question, I sincerely hope so, and probably not.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Hermione didn’t kill him, but that doesn’t mean he isn’t dead.**

We see him up and running (briefly) later in the battle:

> **[Harry] saw Ron and Neville bringing down Fenrir Greyback,** Aberforth Stunning Rookwood, Arthur and Percy flooring Thicknesse, and Lucius and Narcissa Malfoy running through the crowd, not even attempting to fight, screaming for their son.
>
> — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 36 (*The Flaw in the Plan*)

So he was only knocked out by her spell.

And the crystal ball wasn’t Hermione, it was Professor Trelawney. If you read the following paragraph:

> Then, with a bright white flash and a crack, a crystal ball fell on top of [Greyback’s] head, and he crumpled to the ground and did not move.
>
> “I have more!” shrieked Professor Trelawney from over the banisters. “More for any who want them! Here —”
>
> — *Deathly Hallows*, chapter 32 (*The Elder Wand*)

We don’t know whether he survived the Battle of Hogwarts. Although Hermione didn’t deal a fatal blow, there was plenty more fighting and he might have been killed in the interim. There are plenty of people who would be happy to do the honours.

Comment: Can we rule our Hermione killing him later on in the battle, or are there enough holes in the account of her actions to allow for it?

Comment: I really want her to have killed him, tbh.